# Functional programming and the closure term birth

Tags: functional-programming, closures, lambda-calculus

I'm studying functional programming and lambda calculus but I'm wondering
if the closure term is also present in the Church's original work or it's a more modern
term strictly concerned to programming languages.

I remember that in the Church's work there were the terms: free variable, closed into...,
and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following function definition in Scheme:

```
(define (adder a)
  (lambda (x) (+ a x)))
```

The notion of explicit closure is not required in the pure lambda calculus, because variable substitution takes care of it. The above code snippet can be translated

```
λa λx . (a + x)
```

When you apply this to a value `z`, it becomes

```
λx . (z + x)
```

by β-reduction, which involves substitution. You can call this closure over `a` if you want.

(The example uses a function argument, but this holds true for any variable binding, since in the pure lambda calculus all variable bindings must occur via λ terms.)

Comment: So in the Church's work a lambda expression "is closed" over its free variables but the closure term is not explicitly said in that work!

Comment: @xdevel2000 Actually, not over its free variables, but over the ones bound by λ abstractions. Similarly, in a programming language such as Scheme, closure does not occur over free variables: after `(define (adder x) (+ a x))` where `a` is not yet defined, `(define a 2)` changes the behavior of `adder`. Not all programming languages allow this, of course.

Answer (score 3):

It is a more modern term, due to (as many things in modern FP are), P. J. Landin (1964), [The mechanical evaluation of expressions](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~crary/819-f09/Landin64.pdf)

> Also we represent the value of a λ-expression by a
>   bundle of information called a "closure," comprising
>   the λ-expression and the environment relative to which
>   it was evaluated.